# Sharing constant variables between Java and C prior to build

Tags: java, c

The title isn't clear on this but I wasn't sure how to state it:

I am trying to write software in C for an embedded application that communicates over the Modbus protocol with software written in Java run on a different device. These applications need to know the shared Modbus addresses they will be accessing.

It would be nice if there were some way to share variables between these applications without having to update it in both projects. i.e. you could have a key value like "IR_SIGNAL_ADDR=4001" that would be written as

public static final IR_SIGNAL_ADDR = 4001; in java

const int IR_SIGNAL_ADDR = 4001; in C

whenever it is built. I was thinking of making a script that would "build" this file into two constants files for Java and C. Is there a preferable solution to this?

Comment: Have your constants in a Json file.  Write code that reads this and generate what you need in each project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using external common file like properties of json and access them in your code from those files.